# Identify files already committed to Git repository which are excluded by .gitignore

Tags: windows, gratis, software-development, git, version-control

I work with students and the following happens fairly often:

1. Student creates code
2. Student compiles
3. Students adds everything to Git repository, and everything includes `.obj`, `.exe` and whatnot
4. I talk to them that not all files should be committed, and I mention `.gitignore` so they learn something
5. Student deletes the repo and starts over again

In most cases, that's it. No worries. There's not much more code beyond "Hello world".

Now, I have such a repository in real life. I can't simply delete it. I created the `.gitignore` now, but the files are already part of the repo.

I now want to figure out which files that *should* be excluded from the repo but are *actually* committed. I can do that manually, but that's tedious if your `.gitignore` is ~300 lines.

So I need:

- a tool that compares `.gitignore` against files actually in the repo as described above
- is gratis, open source preferred
- works on Windows 10+

Maybe:

- the tool can delete those files from the repo (by making a new commit to remove them, not remove them from history).

Comment: git itself? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466764/git-command-to-show-which-specific-files-are-ignored-by-gitignore

Comment: @Destroy666: thanks. I'll try that